# Aligning divs in odd layouts

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my divs as per the picture I've attached.

[image]

Please excuse the bad doodle.

I've tried a few approaches to get the desired layout but when I get close my divs spill out.

Here's [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/qbqzsL7a/3/)

All help Is really appreciated :)

```
              <div id="bigbox">
                <div id="box1">
                   <div id="innerbox1">

                     <div id="box-image">
                        <a href="course.html">
                            <p id="image-text">
                                Image text</p></a>
                    </div>


                 <div id="box2">
                   <div id="innerbox2">


                  <div id="box3">
                    <div id="innerbox3">



                         <div id="box-image2">
                            <a href="blog.html">
                            <p id="image-text2">
                                Image text</p></a>

                         </div>
                    <div id="box4">
                      <div id="innerbox4">
                        <div id="bluebox">
                    </div></div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Why does box3 have such a large margin from box1? What's the layout logic?

Comment: @Passerby Actually it doesn't need to be so much. Actually it would be better if box 4 ended where box 3 does come to think of it. Box 1 and 3 will be images and box 2 will be a slider that is taller than it is wide with controls under it. Box 4 is text. I guess I wanted the margin there so box 3 and 4 end at the same point.

Comment: It called "masonry layout".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I am doing this, but, here is a quick stab at it. You can adjust the heights and widths as you see fit.

http://codepen.io/scottstreit/pen/epzjBp

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col col1">
    <div class="box1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="Box 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col col2">
    <div class="box2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x600" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="box4">
      <p>Dreamcatcher Wes Anderson photo booth ugh, drinking vinegar Brooklyn ethical occupy. Single-origin coffee butcher next level ethical tofu mumblecore, Brooklyn umami High Life hella hoodie taxidermy four dollar toast. Farm-to-table cray fanny pack
        chillwave. Wayfarers ennui four loko next level yr banjo retro brunch, irony lumbersexual Kickstarter keffiyeh leggings semiotics.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}
div.col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```